# Is there any alternative method to export ggvis to PNG, rather than export_png()?

Tags: r, ggvis

I was wondering if somebody knows any alternative method to export ggvis objects to PNG. Can be implemented on Linux or Windows.

Thanks

Comment: I would just take a screen shot and crop it if I can't find a method

Comment: My objective was to do it in programmatically manner. I would like to embed the plots in a document using knitr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found several ways, I'm posting the one that is more straight forward.

## Required Libraries

```
library(ggvis)
library(XML)
library(webshot)
library(htmltools)
```

## Generating the ggvis and printing the HTML local directory

```
outfile <- mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>% layer_smooths() %>% set_options(width = 1200, height = 800)  %>% view_static() %>% html_print( background = "white", viewer = getOption("viewer", utils::browseURL))
```

## Parsing the HTML to a character vector

```
webst <- htmlParse(outfile, asText=FALSE)
showMethods(class=class(webst), where=search())
webst <- as(webst, "character")
class(webst)
```

## Using regular expressions to search for the name of the SVG object inside the HTML code / Generating the HTML Selector

```
id <- webst %>% sub(pattern = "-container.*", replacement ="") %>% sub(pattern = ".*plot_", replacement ="") 
selec <- paste0("#plot_", id, " > div > svg")
```

## Using Webshot to capture a screenshot of the browser.

```
webshot(outfile, "test_webshot8.png",  selector = selec)
```

## Output

[image]

If you have suggestions how to simplify or a better method will be appreciated.

Comment: It works even if you include it on a pdf with knitr, though you lose any interactivity.  I hope knitr and ggvis fix this problems soon. We don't want to write a really long code just to print a graphic.

Comment: It seems that just 
outfile <- mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>% layer_smooths() %>% set_options(width = 480, height = 360)  %>% view_static() %>% html_print( background = "white", viewer = getOption("viewer", utils::browseURL))
webshot(outfile, "Plot1.png")
works